# Python: If else loop behaving differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to perform operations on a particular combinations of a dataframe but my code is running not according to my thinking and I don't think I have done some visible error.

```
years_list = []
check1 = 1
check10 = 1
r =30

for p in combinations(test4.index,r):
    den = np.mean(p)
    num = np.std(p)
    cv = num/den
    if (den >= 561 and den <= 570 ) :
       if(cv>=0.13 or cv <= 0.17 and check1):
          check1=0
          print("Combination 1 done")

    elif(den>=391 and den <= 400):
        if(cv>=0.13 or cv < 0.17 and check10):
           check10 = 0
           print("Combination 10 done")
    if(check1+check10==0)
        break
```

Here , I am changing the value of `check1` and `check10` to `0` so that the loop enters only once inside the if else condition and if both the criteria are met then it breaks the loop.
`Test4.index` is a dataframe , information about which I guess should be irrelevant.
Its output is printing `Combination 10 done` multiple times which should not happen.
Am I doing some very fundamental mistake or it something more deep error, I am unable to figure out?

Edit:I pasted indentation wrong , Now I pasted it correctly.

Comment: Add `print()` calls in your loop that will show you every iteration  what the code is doing. See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your parenthesis are wrong.

Check the following code:

```
check1 = 0

if(True or True and check1):
    print("valid")
else:
    print("invalid")
```

**Output:**

> valid

if you want to have the conditions properly verified, use:

```
check1 = 0

if(True or True) and check1:
    print("valid")
else:
    print("invalid")
```

**Output:**

> invalid

or in your case:

```
if(cv>=0.13 or cv < 0.17) and check10:
    check10 = 0
    print("Combination 10 done")
```

check the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in python to know which one will be evaluated first

Comment: @Bing nice. Accept the answer if definitely solves your problem

Comment: Of course `cv` will always be greater or equal to `0.13` or smaller than `0.17`. The OP might want to recheck this condition.

Answer (score 1):

since you got the answer already

I say you could refactor last conditional block of code using logical AND operator to check instead of 0+0.

```
if(check1 == 0 and check10 == 0)
break
```

for more assurance, you could print check1 and check 10 values at end of the loop to evaluate for each iteration